# Compute Tag Co-occurrence in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am a Hive novice looking to compute *tag co-occurrence.* I have a table in Hive containing all the tags which exist in each document:

```
(docID STRING, tag STRING)
```

For example:

---

**docID, tag**

- 1, dog
- 1, cat
- 1, horse
- 2, dog
- 2, cat
- 2, bone

---

I am looking for a Hive query which could compute all the tag co-occurrences for each pair.

The output should be:

```
(tagA STRING, tagB STRING, co-occurrence INT)
```

For the above example:

---

**tagA, tagB, co-occurrence**

- dog, cat, 2
- dog, horse, 1
- dog, bone, 1
- cat, dog, 2
- cat, horse, 1
- cat, bone, 1

---

Does anyone a Hive query which would achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A.tag, B.tag, COUNT(*)
FROM tags A JOIN tags B
ON A.docId = B.docId
GROUP BY A.tag, B.tag;
```

Note: this will not include 0s, e.g. (horse, bone, 0) would not be in the output